# Importing a file

Tags: android

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

Friends Please tell me how to import this file in android. MY Eclipse is giving me option 
`import org,apache.commons.*;` still it is not importing the file I am looking.

Comment: `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` is successfully imported in my machine...are you sure add .jar file libs folder...

Comment: The library might not be in path, or the library you have may not have the required class file.

Comment: have you tried the below ans???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be this package is not there in your eclipse.
Dont worry. You Can download it from Here:
[Take package from here.](http://commons.apache.org/) or [here](http://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi).
After download the class FileUtils will be founded easily.

Comment: You can see [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11687667/revisions) by clicking on their date.

Comment: @Pshemo, Can you tell me? How to check this?? Whether its right or wrong please..

Comment: Yes,That i know. I am asking that when i am answering any question, then how can I take care of this things?

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking for. Do you want to know how to create good answer (if yes then this [answer] may help), or maybe do you want to know how to check if your answer is correct or something else?

Comment: This is exactly i wanted to know that how to answer??

Comment: For more info read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can also find many useful informations on http://meta.stackoverflow.com for example [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) or kind of another FAQ [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).